# Whats a good typical network timeout?

Tags: android, networking

I am using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ to get simple JSON data from Reddit (just a constant) feed of links from a popular subreddit `r/news` I was wondering what is a reasonable request timeout in milliseconds for Android apps talking to JSON backend endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable timeout will be in seconds, not milliseconds. How long depends entirely on the expected service time of the server. You might want to consider the mean service time plus two or three standard deviations, but you will need to assemble the statistics on that first.